# Dynamic Proxy: how to handle nested method calls

Tags: java, proxy, nested, invocationhandler

I'm trying to learn Dynamic Proxies in Java.

I know how they work but I can't find a solution to my problem: given an interface and its implementation with methods a(), b() and c() nested one into the other (let's say a() calls b() which calls c()), I would like to proxy my object to log EACH call to the methods.

So I code my InvocationHandler such as the invoke() method prints a log-line before the execution.

But when I call proxy.a(), only the call of method a() is logged and not the whole chain of methods.

What am I missing? Is the target of the proxy have to be a proxy itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the object itself doesn't know that it is being proxied, so when a() calls b(), it will be a normal "intra object" call.

If the target of the proxy is the proxy itself, you will have a loop.

One way to solve this, if it's really needed, would be to introduce a delegate to the target object and set it up with the proxy or with itself as delegate. Strange, but might work. Look out for loops, though.

Comment: do you mean using a proxied obj instead of the obj inside the invocation handler? i tried instead to let the invocation handler extends my object's class and apply the invoke method on the same invochandler instance ( method.invoke(this, args), i thought it would pretend to be the object but having each method call filtered by the proxy ), but once again it fails.

Answer (score 2):

It is because, while from your test code you are calling `proxy.a()`, your final `a()` method is not calling `proxy.b()`, but straight to the self instance `b()` .

As a workaround, you can overload every method passing it a delegate instance. Suposing a class name of MyClass and a interface name of MyInterface:

```
void a() {
   //to keep the non-proxy working, the default method have to pass the 
   //self intance
   a(this);
}
void a(MyInterface target) {
   target.b(target);
}

void b() {
   b(this);
}
void b(MyInterface target) {
   target.c(target);
}
void c() {
   c(this);
}
void c(MyInterface target) {
   //do whatever
}
```

Then, from your test code you'll be able to call `proxy.a(proxy)`, and get the expected result.